# Cancel INSERT if value in referenced table is null or zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a couple of tables that are related to each other. engine: myisam

1:

```
account
account_ID, account_username, account_pwd, ......
```

2:

```
items
items_account_ID, items_name, ......
```

As you can see, items have a column `items_account_ID`. Every item belongs to an 
account. To insert an item I use a query like:

```
INSERT INTO items SET items_name = 'asd', items_account_ID = (SELECT account_ID FROM account WHERE account_ID = accountValue AND account_pwd='something');
```

This query is created in asp.net and accountValue is from SESSION or hidden field of something. the SELECT statement is for security reasons so that users can't create items for each other.

I would like to cancel the `INSERT` if the account_ID doesn't exist. Something like:

...." items_account_ID = IFNULL(theSelectStatement, "cancelQuery()");

But I can't find any function in mysql to cancel the current query.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you ought to define `items_account_ID` as `not null` and make sure it references `account(account_ID)` as a foreign key. Doing so will prevent you from inserting a bad `account_ID` into `items`.

Then you might consider rewriting your insert as follows:

```
insert items 
(
     items_name
    ,items_account_ID
)
select
'asd'
,account_ID
from account 
where account_ID = accountValue 
and account_pwd = 'something'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sounds like an excellent way of doing it, didn't think of Select all values. Thanks!

Comment: This will work even without the `FOREIGN KEY` declaration (which would need changing tables form MyISAM to InnoDB to work)

Comment: Even so, he still ought to implement his relationships properly.